# How can I avoid dribbling spit at night?

Tags: bedroom, sleeping

How can I avoid dribbling spittle when I sleep? While this is not uncomfortable while sleeping, waking up with a wet pillow is not very nice and is a little dirty.

Some precision: This happens only occasionally and, the amounts of saliva are small and equivalent to about one spit, I would say.

Answer (score 2):

If you could manage to sleep on your back, it could minimize the occasions when this happens.

Putting a towel over the pillow case will absorb some of the moisture to further minimize the problem of a wet pillow case.

As an experiment, try using mouth wash as the last step in your nightly oral hygiene regimen. The wash ensure there are no sweets in your mouth that might encourage salivating.

Answer (score 1):

Elevate your head a bit more.

Sleep on your back.

Try practicing breathing deeply or through your nose.

Brush your teeth directly before bed (?).

For decreased moonlit salivation, avoid nighttime sour or sugary foods, but perhaps have a salty snack.

Also, if you are drooling for more, visit [here](http://www.enkivillage.com/drooling-while-sleeping.html) and [here](http://docslide.us/documents/sialorreapdf.html).

Check with your doctor to make sure you do not have a condition, like Diphtheria or an allergy.

Sleeping with your mouth open *will not* dry out your mouth. It will give you a sore throat, but clenching your teeth can give you serious health problems, though closing your mouth might help.

As a last resort, duct tape your mouth closed, your arms together, and close the trunk behind you. Good luck with your moist dreams!